# Angular RxJS filter - Return an empty or populated Observable list

Tags: angular, rxjs6

In the "search" service method, I am returning items where the name includes the search keyword:

```
// data.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, pipe, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, flatMap  } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Goodie } from './models/Goodie';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  public goodies = [
    { name: 'Brownie Pillow Cookie'},
    { name: 'Talenti Pistachio' },
    { name: 'SnickerDoodle' }
];
  constructor() {}

  public getGoodies(): Observable<Goodie[]> {
    return of(this.goodies);
  }

  public search(keyword): Observable<Goodie> {
    return this.getGoodies().pipe(
      flatMap(data => data),
      filter(g => g.name.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase()))
    );
  }
}
```

This works (returns items), when there is a keyword match on name. For example, searching for "e" returns results, which I can see displayed in the console:

```
// app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Goodie } from './models/Goodie';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public searchResult: Goodie[] = [];

  constructor(private storeService: DataService) {}

  handleSearch(type, keyword) {
      this.searchResult = [];
      this.storeService.search(keyword).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('-----------');
      this.searchResult.push(data);
      console.log(this.searchResult);
      console.log('-----------');
    });
  }
}
```

But if I search for a keyword that does not match any items, for example "x", then not only are no results returned, but nothing is logged to the console from inside the this.storeService.search(keyword).subscribe method - the console does not even print the statement console.log('-----------').

As a result, I'm hoping to get clarification on two things:

1. Does the body of the handleSearch subscribe method even run if rxjs operations yield no results for filter?
2. What is a recommended way to get this to work so that tthis.storeService.search(keyword).subscribe always returns results, even if it is an empty list (similar to es6 array filter where an empty array is returned if no matches, but an object is always returned).

Here is the example on StackBlitz: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/cookies-bakery

Comment: I would recommend using the `array.filter` function instead of the observable filter function, after all, you want to filter the array and not the observable stream from the sounds of it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/cookies-bakery-4teedg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user184994 says, use plain old array.filter to get your results.

As you surmise, an observable of individual items (vs observable of array) is not going to emit anything when the search matches nothing.

This fixes your example code,

```js
public search(keyword): Observable<Goodie[]> {
  // return this.getGoodies().pipe(
  //   flatMap(data => data),
  //   filter(g => g.name.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase()))
  // );
  return of(
    this.goodies.filter(g => 
      g.name.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
    )
  );
}
```

But if you absolutely need a stream of individual items in your component, you can emit an error from the search when nothing is found, and catch it in the subscribe.

```js
public search(keyword): Observable<Goodie> {
  const results = this.goodies.filter(g => 
    g.name.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
  );
  return results.length ? from(results) : throwError("Not found"); 
}


handleSearch(keyword) {
  this.searchResult = [];
  this.storeService.search(keyword).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log('-----------');
      this.searchResult.push(data);
      console.log(this.searchResult);
      console.log('-----------');
    },
    err => this.err = err
  );
}
```

Here is the ammended [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cookies-bakery-mptxm6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

---

Or, if you do not like using error handling as part of the logic, your service can emit an observable of the results count which can be subscribed separately in the component.